# Hadith: I pray two prayers only

Tags: source-identification

What is the source of the [hadith mentioned in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1g-ghXViSEQ). (It starts at about 7:07).

(In short, a man came to the Messenger (piece and blessings be upon him), and said he was ready to give his pledge but he would pray only two prayers daily (instead of five). And the Messenger accepted.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hadith was narrated in Musnad Ahmad:

- In the first Musnad of the Basri narrators -see [here](https://fatwa.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=6&bookhad=19776) in Arabic-:

  <sub>In the following I'll translate from Arabic, as these translations are of my own take them with the necessary care! My additions are added in italic</sub>

  > 19776 حدثنا  محمد بن جعفر حدثنا  شعبة عن  قتادة عن نصر بن عاصم عن رجل منهم أنه أتى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فأسلم على أنه لا يصلي إلا صلاتين فقبل ذلك منه
  >
  > We have been informed from Muhammad ibn Ja'afar (*also known as Ghandar*) from Sho'bah (*ibn al-Hajjaj*) from Qatadah (*ibn Di'amah*<sup>(1)</sup>) from Nassr ibn 'Assim from (*ibn 'Omar al-Laithi*<sup>(2)</sup>) a man among them that he came to the prophet Allahs prayers and blessings be upon him and embraced Islam with the condition (or making it a condition) not to pray except with two prayers (*a day*) and it was accepted from him.
  >
  > <sup>(1) The known mufassir and muhadith.</sup>
  >   <sup>(2) So far all the narrators are from Basra and have a high level of trustworthiness.</sup>
- In the Musnad of the rest of al-Ansar -see [here](https://fatwa.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=6&bookhad=22570) in Arabic-:

  > 22570 حدثنا  وكيع حدثنا  شعبة عن  قتادة عن نصر بن عاصم الليثي عن رجل منهم أنه أتى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فأسلم على أن يصلي صلاتين فقبل منه
  >
  > We have been informed from Waki'a (*ibn al-Jarah*)<sup>(1)</sup> from Sho'bah (*ibn al-Hajjaj*) from Qatadh (*ibn Di'amah*) from Nasr ibn 'Assim (*ibn 'Omar*) al-Laithi <sup>(2)</sup> from a man among them
  >   that he came to the prophet Allahs prayers and blessings be upon him and embraced Islam making the condition to pray only two prayers (*a day*) and it was accepted from him.
  >
  > <sup>(1) The known scholar from al-Kufa.</sup>
  >   <sup>(2) So far all narrators are from 'Iraq, Waki'a وكيع is from Kufa and the others from Basra and all are of a high level of trustworthiness.</sup>

In both narrations the final narrator is not named. So far I was not able to clarify whether he is considered as unknown or whether he was named somewhere else or by some later editor or hadith scholar.

In his commentary on Jabir's hadith from Sahih al-Bukhari -see [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/50)- ibn Hajar referred to one of the above narrations in Fath al-Bari -see [here](https://fatwa.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=302&ID=655) in Arabic- and added the explanation of Imam Ahmad:

> قال  الإمام أحمد في رواية ابنه عبد الله  : إذا أسلم على أن يصلي صلاتين يقبل منه ، فإذا دخل يؤمر بالصلوات الخمس ، وذكر حديث  قتادة عن نصر بن عاصم الذي تقدم .
>
> Imam Ahmad said in the narration of his son 'Abdullah: If he (*a person*) embraced Islam under the condition to pray only two prayers this is accepted for him. Once he embraces Islam he's (*must be*) ordered to pray the five prayers. Then he mentioned the hadith of Qatadah from Nasr ibn 'Asim that was mentioned earlier.

In his Nayl al-Awtar -see [here](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=2367&idto=2368&bk_no=47&ID=1002)- a-Shawkani compiled the hadith among other  conditional pledges of allegiance such as [this](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/20/98) from Sunan abi Dawod saying that these ahadith show that it is allowed to accept the pledges of allegiance and the conversion of (former) disbelievers even if the conditions under which they gave them are void and that accepting Islam by a person who does it with reservation or reluctantly. And he quoted a long quote of al-Khattabi in which he claimed that there are even variations of the hadith quoting one single prayer.

Answer (score 2):

It is found in e.g. Musnad Ahmad ibn Hanbal: [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13157/23545#p1) and [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13157/20652#p1), the text of the narrations there is:

> حدثنا وكيع، حدثنا شعبة، عن قتادة، عن نصر بن عاصم الليثي، عن رجل منهم، أنه أتى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فأسلم على أن يصلي صلاتين فقبل منه

and

> حدثنا محمد بن جعفر، حدثنا شعبة، عن قتادة، عن نصر بن عاصم، عن رجل منهم، أنه أتى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فأسلم على أنه لا يصلي إلا صلاتين، فقبل ذلك منه

The translation is what you have given. An unnamed companion narrates that he came to the Prophet ﷺ to accept Islam on the condition that he would not pray except for two prayers. The Prophet ﷺ accepted it.

Comment: Could you kindly translate that?