# Reference for Hadith?

Tags: hadith, salat, source-identification

i would like to find a hadith i cannot find. It goes like A man comes to the prophet (ﷺ) and he says he would accept Islam however he won't do a certain part of the Salah ( He won't do Sujud/Do Ruku?) and the prophet (ﷺ) accepts. I'm 99% sure this hadith exists in some form like this but I cannot find it online. I apologise if this too vague but this is what I remember

Comment: Isn't this covered in [Hadith I pray two prayers only](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/55722/hadith-i-pray-two-prayers-only/55728#55728)?

Comment: @user40139 Wa Iyyak for you answer comment given to my answer.

Answer (score -2):

I have heard a hadith by mufti that our beloved prophet said "I was assisted by youth". نصرث بالشباب